# Reentering updated contact records in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am creating a journey where we need to evaluate new records coming in Data extension, this part is working well. But, there are some contacts who are re-subscribing and their existing contact record in Data Extension gets updated with new values with same EmailAddress (Subscriber Key & Primary Key is Email Address)
We need these newly updated contacts too to be entered in journey.
Upon selecting option  'Evaluate new records only' it only allows newly created records and not updated one's. On selection of 'Evaluate all records' it allows all the contacts in DE evetime the journey is run irrespective to new or old.

What could be the best way to configure journey to allow only New and Updated records?

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by creating a Boolean flag on the DE. Set the default value to be 'Y'. Each time a record is modified or a record is added, use a sql to update this. The logic of update depends on how you are storing the records, whether you have a modified date on the DE. The automation will then govern your journey schedule. You can then choose 'Evaluate all records', but put an entry criteria, so that all records with `flag = 'Y'`, will enter the journey. Not sure, if this is the best method, but would work.

Comment: Thanks Swati, something similar I have been doing from past as a workaround. But, was wondering if there's something within journey which can do the job.